# Salesforce API Access without App-Register?

Tags: api, authentication, connected-apps, oauth

We have to design an application and retrieve data from salesforce. Therefore, I have to authenticate my web app to Salesforce to make API calls.

As I [read in the documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=remoteaccess_oauth_username_password_flow.htm&type=5), I need to define our app as an connected app in our Salesforce account. Unfortunately, this function is blocked / disabled for security reason. Therefore I have to search another way to authenticate my app.

On services like mailchimp or segment.io, I can give access for these services to salesforce with my username and password  (RemoteAccessAuthorizationPage) without define the app as a 'Connected App.

Is it possible to achieve the same with our webapp and connect trough username and password without to have to define the app as a connected app?

Thanks for your support!

Answer (score 2):

You can use the SOAP API's [login](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_calls_login.htm) to authenticate, and then use that session ID as a REST token like normal.

Answer (score 1):

Just create a [free Developer Edition org](https://developer.salesforce.com/signup) and create the connected app from there. Salesforces requires you to register your web application before it issues you an API key but it doesn't have to be from your company's production org.

Comment: Thank you, I got it... Just one question: For authentication, I need the user security token, additionally to the user username and password. Why do I didn't need this by authentication with mailchimp?

Comment: Just an added layer of security that Salesforce provides. If the IP Address of the user is whitelisted, then a security token wouldn't be required. If you plan to use OAuth2 or WebServer authentication, then your users could login into your web app the same way they log into Salesforce (without needing a security token)

Comment: you made me to think connected app whole different way. probably I should ask as a new question, when connected app credentials can be used in any integration irrespective of org, what is the exact use of connect app then ?

Comment: yea, it's a good question. Take Twitter or Github for example, they ask you to register (name, email, etc.) before issuing an API token. Salesforce probably decided to let you register by an org instead of a user. Essentially, it's just a drawn-out registration that also includes a sandbox. For me, I usually have one development org per Connected App and then a personal org for things like Trailhead